# In light of genetic genealogy, are there any new theories for the introduction of Goidelic to Britain and Ireland

Tags: language, britain, ireland, migration, genealogy

There is DNA evidence of two major waves of Indo-European migration to Britain and Ireland.
The first wave of migration occurred in the early Bronze Age.
The second wave of migration occurred in the middle Bronze Age. https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/view/PRJEB47891?show=reads

Descendants of the Indo-European Y haplogroup R-L21 appear to have first reached Britain then later Ireland.  http://scaledinnovation.com/gg/snpTracker.html?snp=R-A744

The Indo-European languages Goidelic and Brythonic are theorized to have split from a common parent language around 3200 BCE.  https://www.pnas.org/content/100/15/9079

Gaelic and Welsh are not recognizable as related languages except by linguistic analysis.  There is no dialect cline between Gaelic and Welsh as there is between Gàidhlig and Gaoluinn.

Comment: What is the actual question here?

Comment: I see the question as "Has recent genetic research (as cited) affected prevailing theories among historians as to the origins of the Goidelic speaking peoples?" Disclaimer: I myself belong to haplogroup R-L21.